# Android Back Stack navigation

Tags: android, back-stack, android-navigation

Let's say that I have a back stack like this:

`A -> B -> C -> B -> D`
(D is the top)

And I need to open a new `B` Activity in the same task but in the second position 
so :

`A -> B (new)` (`B` new now is the top of the stack)

---

If I use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` the result is (obviously): `A -> B-> C-> B (new)` but this is not what I want.

---

Maybe navigation of my app is wrong so I explain it.

- A is a home screen.
- B is a detail of an object
- C is a list of objects
- B is a detail of the object clicked on the list
- D is an activity with a dialog where positive button would point you on the first `B` and negative button just dismiss the dialog

How to solve this?

Comment: One way would be to finish the activities manually till B or by starting an activityforResult and give it a requestcode which you can use later use from a point to startActivity B. Or the other way would be to call A that interns opens B with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. That way you will end up to B. I would rather take an approach where I just call Activity A which in turns open activity B.

Comment: Ahmed thanks! I used tha last approach, now I open the activity A with clear_top and on the OnNewIntent of the activity A I open the activity B